# How can I tell if a script was run in the background and with nohup?

Tags: bash, shell, sh, nohup

Ive got a script that takes a quite a long time to run, as it has to handle many thousands of files.  I want to make this script as fool proof as possible.  To this end, I want to check if the user ran the script using nohup and '&'.   E.x. 
`me@myHost:/home/me/bin $ nohup doAlotOfStuff.sh &`.   I want to make 100% sure the script was run with nohup and '&', because its a very painful recovery process if the script dies in the middle for whatever reason.

How can I check those two key paramaters inside the script itself? and if they are missing, how can I stop the script before it gets any farther, and complain to the user that they ran the script wrong?  Better yet, is there way I can force the script to run in nohup &?

Edit: the server enviornment is AIX 7.1

Comment: May I ask why are you not using `screen` or `tmux`?

Comment: They are basically terminal multiplexers. They let you open a detached session in a remote computer (or in a local one). I highly recommend using one of them. `screen` is simpler while `tmux` has more power.

Comment: Hey I accidentally deleted my previous comment.  Those commands dont work in AIX, which is my server enviornment.  Plus, I feel as if that isnt getting at the root cause of the problem.  I want to make it so even the stupidest of users cant mess the script up =)

Comment: one way to simplify this is to create an `alias` for your command, something like `alias doAlotOfStuff='nohup doAlotOfStuff.sh &'`

Comment: Write a wrapper script with the correct commands (nohup, & etc) and pass on that script to the user.

Comment: `screen` most certainly can be compiled on AIX, I've done that. On the other hand, instead of `nohup` you can use `trap '' HUP` inside the script. Also the script can run itself in the background if that's neccessary: `"$0" "$@" &` and then `echo "started in background"; exit`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ps` utility can get the process state. The process state code will contain the character `+` when running in foreground. Absence of `+` means code is running in background.

However, it will be hard to tell whether the background script was invoked using `nohup`. It's also almost impossible to rely on the presence of `nohup.out` as output can be redirected by user elsewhere at will.

There are 2 ways to accomplish what you want to do. Either bail out and warn the user or automatically restart the script in background.

```
#!/bin/bash
local mypid=$$
if [[ $(ps -o stat= -p $mypid) =~ "+" ]]; then
    echo Running in foreground.
    exec nohup $0 "$@" &
    exit
fi
# the rest of the script
...
```

In this code, if the process has a state code `+`, it will print a warning then restart the process in background. If the process was started in the background, it will just proceed to the rest of the code.

If you prefer to bailout and just warn the user, you can remove the exec line. Note that the `exit` is not needed after `exec`. I left it there just in case you choose to remove the `exec` line.

Comment: Which of the two ways do you think would be most preferable?

Comment: If you don't want users to run the command with output redirected to `/dev/null` or some other files as `doAlotOfStuff.sh > /dev/null 2>&1` and not knowi that it actually bailed out until the next day when they check the redirected output, then it's better to automatically restart in background.

Answer (score 1):

One good way to find if a script is logging to nohup, is to first check that the nohup.out exists, and then to echo to it and ensure that you can read it there. For example:

```
echo "complextag"
if ( $(cat nohup.out | grep "complextag" ) != "complextag" );then
    # various commands complaining to the user, then exiting
fi
```

This works because if the script's stdout is going to nohup.out, where they should be going (or whatever out file you specified), then when you echo that phrase, it should be appended to the file nohup.out. If it doesn't appear there, then the script was nut run using nohup and you can scold them, perhaps by using a wall command on a temporary broadcast file. (if you want me to elaborate on that I can).

As for being run in the background, if it's not running you should know by checking nohup.